# unable to open jupyter notebook due to accent characters

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-2.x

I just installed Anaconda, which also install jupyter. I'm unable to run `jupyter notebook` on windows 8.1 command, because it seems to be using the default installation path for jupyter even though I explicitly set Anaconda to install in a different path.

The default path which jupyter is trying to load is C:\Users\Vinícius\.jupyter and I set Anaconda to install at C:\Vinicius. The first path has an accent, and the second doesn't.

When I try to run `jupyter notebook` or `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=C:\\Temp\\` or `jupyter notebook --generate-config` commands, they all fail due to the first path with an accent? What should I do to fix this?

The errors for `jupyter notebook` or `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=C:\\Temp\\` are:

> Could not decode 'C:\Users\Vin\xedcius.jupyter' for unicode trait
>   'config_dir' of a NotebookApp instance.

Comment: Which python do you use? 2.7? 3? Seem like according to this [github issue](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/444#issuecomment-190104682) python 2.7 have a problem with non ASCII home.

Comment: I downloaded python 2.7 from Anaconda website. Only solution is to use python 3?

Comment: Python 3 would fix a lot of unicode problem you could have. While I would recommend it you can do some fix yourself, I think the github link I've sent give some fix (you'll have to change [some files](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/444#issuecomment-190216159)). Any reason for not using python 3?

Comment: Nops. Just used to work with 2.7. It's for an online course I bought on udemy, so not sure yet which issues with python 2/3 I may find. I'll give it a shot with python 3. Thanks

Comment: If you try the fix they say it would work with python 2.7, but we can't say if you won't have a problem with that later. If you don't have any strict requirement I would recommend using python 3 in your case. I'll post what I said in comment as answer, if it fixed your problem don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [github issues](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/444) python 2.7 have a lot of problem with non-ascii path.

I would recommend using python 3 who have less problem with that (according to the research I've made most people said using python 3 fixed the problem).

If you still need to use 2.7 for any reasons then according to the same github issues some people managed to use 2.7 with non-ascii path by changing [some files](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/444#issuecomment-190216159).
Here is what they said:

> I found the decision: in file
> C:\Path\to\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py you need to append
> .decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()) at the line end:
>
> in function get_homedir:

```
homedir = os.path.realpath(homedir).decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

> in function jupyter_data_dir:

```
appdata = os.environ.get('APPDATA', None).decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

> After that jupyter notebook started on my Windows!

While it may fix the problem I can't say if it won't cause other problem later.

Edit: I want to add that while there may be a lot of work around to avoid this error (changing the patch of config_dir for one without non ascii character?) if you have this problem in one case you may have it with other modules or command, switching to python 3 who handle it better would, I think, be easier.

Comment: I ended up using python 3. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Don't worry, Python 3 isn't that different from Python 2. Also most of the module in python 2 are also work with python 3.